# joda datetime with timezone offset, after insert to DB will change to UTC time

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I am using jodatime now, but I got one issue recently, which is: when I get a joda time (it always with timezone offset), say `2017-01-31T00:00:00.000+08:00`, after I insert this value to database (I am using Hibernate4 as my ORM framework), the value will automatically convert to UTC time, which is `1/30/2017 4:00:00 PM` (I am using IBM DB2, tried MySql also same). And when I retrieve it from database, it will convert back to `2017-01-31T00:00:00.000+08:00`.

Just wondering why this happens? Can I do some global configuration on this? I want to store local time instead of UTC time in database (something like `1/31/2017 0:00:00 AM`), so I need to change DB setting or do it at code level? Really no much experience on this timezone handling, can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What are you wanting to "configure"? What is it doing that you don't like?

Comment: I am just thinking can I do some one time configuration to solve this, what I don't like is manipulations on each single `DateTime` object.

Comment: You haven't explained *what's wrong*. In particular, you really should be using UTC for everything internally, especially in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours' investigation, I finally found the solution for this issue, since I am using Hibernate, what I need to do is just add below line to hibernate config xml:

```
<property name="jadira.usertype.databaseZone">Asia/Singapore</property>
<property name="jadira.usertype.javaZone">Asia/Singapore</property>
```

alternatively:

```
<property name="jadira.usertype.databaseZone">jvm</property>
<property name="jadira.usertype.javaZone">jvm</property>
```

Now everything works fine.